# How do you use patterndb variables in syslog-ng?

Tags: syslog, syslog-ng

I'd like to parse some custom (*network appliance*) syslog files to create my own formatted output.

As I am new to syslog-ng & patterndb I have been trying to build an example using the documentation - my work so far is here: https://gist.github.com/linickx/8002981

In the example, I would like to read the syslog file (testfile.log):

```
Accepted password for sampleuser from 10.50.0.247 port 42156 ssh2
Accepted password for user from 10.51.0.27 port 4256 ssh2
```

And output just a list of usernames & ip addresses, like:

```
sampleuser; 10.50.0.247;
user; 10.51.0.27;
```

To parse the log file I have created the following patterndb (example.xml):

```
<patterndb version='4' pub_date='2010-10-17'>
    <ruleset name='ssh' id='123456678'>
        <pattern>ssh</pattern>
            <rules>
                <rule provider='me' id='182437592347598' class='system'>
                    <patterns>
                        <pattern>Accepted @ESTRING:SSH.AUTH_METHOD: @for @ESTRING:SSH_USERNAME: @from @ESTRING:SSH_CLIENT_ADDRESS: @port @NUMBER:SSH_PORT_NUMBER:@ ssh2</pattern>
                    </patterns>
                    <examples>
                        <example>
                            <test_message program="ssh">Accepted password for sampleuser from 10.50.0.247 port 42156 ssh2</test_message>
                            <test_values>
                                <test_value name="SSH.AUTH_METHOD">password</test_value>
                                <test_value name="SSH_USERNAME">sampleuser</test_value>
                                <test_value name="SSH_CLIENT_ADDRESS">10.50.0.247</test_value>
                                <test_value name="SSH_PORT_NUMBER">42156</test_value>
                            </test_values>
                       </example>
                    </examples>
                </rule>
            </rules>
    </ruleset>
</patterndb>
```

However when I use the SSH_USERNAME & SSH_CLIENT_ADDRESS variables in my syslog-ng.conf

```
destination test_output {
        file("/home/nick/output.log"
                template("${SSH_USERNAME}; ${SSH_CLIENT_ADDRESS}; \n")
                template_escape(no)
        );
};
```

--[ full version can been seen in the GIST ]--

The output file (output.log) is empty

```
; ;
; ;
```

Is there some hierarchy or special way to use custom or patterndb variables in syslog-ng.conf that I am missing?

Thanks in Advance!